# How can I move the window options menu to the top bar in gnome?

Tags: gnome, window, gnome-panel

Currently, the window menu is displayed inside each window like in Microsoft Windows:

[image]

What I want to do is to move that menu ("File", "Edit", et.c.) to the top bar like in unity and macOS:

[image]

How can I do this?